# Adjectival form for "made out of energy"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

I need an adjective that can be made to describe the quality of a structure being made out energy.

The term "energetic" I find mainly defined as something that is "abundant in energy", while the way I need to use it would describe even the state when the structure has little energy.

Until now, I've been using the term "energetical", but it doesn't seem exist in the common use.

Actual example: esoteric human sciences describe the human being as made out of several bodies - the physical body being merely the end product, the grossest manifestation of the condensation of energy. They describe more subtle bodies, amongst which exists the body made out of energy, with its specific anatomy (chakras - energy force centres, nadis (meridians) - subtle energy channels).

I am prone to "create" the word 'energetical', since language is a living entity which is meant to evolve according to the needs - but first want to seek others' council in case an established solution already exists.

Comment: Obviously, while writing longer texts in which the term has to be used frequently to differentiate between the structures made of energy from the ones existing in material or mental form, I cannot use "made out of energy".

Comment: I think in the "real" world (of "**Theoretical** Physics") it's pretty much accepted now that "matter" as such doesn't really exist anyway. It's not just that ***E = mc2*** means we can "convert" matter to energy and vice-versa - in the final analysis, there's ***only*** energy (which sometimes looks like "matter" from certain perspectives and at certain scales). Whatever - for my money, this question is really about an ill-defined *metaphorical* usage that doesn't actually admit of a single unambiguously correct answer.

Comment: @HotLicks: Aw, Snap! (For the nth time? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You've got to be more massive to beat me!

Comment: Thank you for those contributions.
The term "material" however is very much needed, as it described the reality perceived by the basic 5 senses. For those who look to apply rather than to conceptualise it is a valuable distinction from "everything is made out of energy". Decades after Einstein's discovery an everyday person is not even a bit closer to actually accessing the energy concentrated in the matter, nor to understand and control the energy in general. More on the point, the use of genuine methodology gives the possibility to make it a human technology rather than metaphysics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because single word requests should be accompanied by a sentence as an example of the intended use.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something which is called **Energy Body.** In spirituality, it a body which is made out of only energy.

Article on What is Energy Body: http://pranaworld.net/what-is-the-energy-body/

> Based on Master Choa Kok Sui’s research, physical body is composed of two parts: the visible physical body and the invisible physical body. This invisible physical body, also known as **energy body**....

Or

You can use word **Prana** (Sanskrit)

From Merriam Webster,

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prana

> any of the three or more vital currents : the principle of life moving in the human body.

Those three vital currents are  *energy, life, or breath*.

Comment: Hm. Interesting option. As I said - I need to use it for more than just the body.
It will also be needed for things like "energ... blockage", "energy... process", "energ... structure". So you suggest using "energy" as an adjective? interesting.

Comment: @Mayavin Prana (Hinduism) : considered as a life-giving force. Can refer to energy, life, or breath.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if "pranic" would would work in all the instances. Chakra, for instance, is a structure existing at the pranic level, but also at the mental, supra-mental levels. Using a term related to the broader understanding of the word "energy" is much more accurate.

Comment: @Mayavin check out **urja** or **urjamay kosh.**

Comment: I am not sure what you're referring to. No help from google.

Comment: The problem with the passage that it is in "religious language". This differs from "normal" language. In religious language many words tend to have a meaning that is not fully grasped or explained and which practitioners disagree about, even among themselves - a word often means "what I think it means, but not what someone else believes it to be." Given that, **Prana**, (with an initial vague definition) would be my choice - possibly with a qualifying adjective..

Comment: The question asks for an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring phrases around the concept of vitality you can use a  similar construction to energetic. *Vitalic* is less about having an abundance of energy and more about life force:

> **Vitalic** (Adjective)
>
> 1. Pertaining to life, vital

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Vitalic

Though searching in sources such as Websters or Oxford, the word doesn't seem to be listed. However, I would argue that it makes more sense in your context as there is also a school of thought known as "Vitalism"

> Vitalism is the belief that "living organisms are fundamentally
> different from non-living entities because they contain some
> non-physical element or are governed by different principles than are
> inanimate things"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitalism

This seems very related to the ideas you are trying to convey.

Answer (score -1):

In the spirit of “esoteric human sciences” I suggest the *adjective*:

> [**thermodynamic**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thermodynamic) (or **-al**)

I am sure nobody needs reminding of the definition of the thermodynamic concept of [Gibbs Free Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy):

> ΔG = ΔH – TΔS

(Einstein doesn’t really ‘matter’ here because his equation lacks an ‘energetic’ adjective.)

Although this scientific term has not generally been extended in the way that *physical*, *energetic*, *chemical* and even *optical* have, its relative lack of familiarity combined with its authenticity makes it eminently suitable for the unusual context proposed by the poster. Better, by far, to extend a real word than to introduce the clumsy and ugly ‘energetical’ he suggests.

Finally I add a quotation from 1860 (cited in the OED) which illustrates a slightly more general use of the adjective in relation to the natural world:

> By no means the only body of warm water that the *thermo-dynamical* forces of the ocean kept in motion…

Comment: Clearly, this doesn't answer the question. "relating to thermodynamics (= the area of physics connected with the action of heat and other types of energy):"

Comment: @GArthurBrown "Clearly" your comment betrays an overly rigid attitude to the English language. No doubt you would have downvoted Shakespeare for "salad days". The adjective relates to a concept — that of energy — just as physical, chemical, and energetic do. Energetic is more direct but rejected by the poster as it has other associations. Using a related but more esoteric word — one avoids such associations. Don't mistake my scepticism towards the context of the question for lack of conviction in my answer. I am proud of its originality and think it hits the nail right on the head.